# Ajax call to php script that returns python script not working

Tags: php, xampp, webserver

When opening a chart-building file in the browser using localhost, it makes an ajax call to fetch polynomial regression coefficients.

fetch.php:

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    //getting data from one of the series in line chart
    $xValuesStr = implode(',', $data['xValues']);
    $yValuesStr = implode(',', $data['yValues']);
    if(isset($xValuesStr) && isset($yValuesStr)){
        $pathToPyScript = dirname(__DIR__).'/scripts/calcCoefficients.py';
        //Python interpreter location given by sys.executable
        $pathToPythonEXE = 'C:\Users\dylan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe';
        $command = "$pathToPythonEXE $pathToPyScript [".$xValuesStr."] [".$yValuesStr."]";
        // Run the Python script and pass the xValues and yValues as arguments
        //exec($command, $output, $return);
        $output = shell_exec($command);
        // The output will contain the coefficients as a JSON string
        $coefficients = json_decode($output, true);
        // Do something with the coefficients
        var_dump($coefficients);
    }
?>
```

This script returns the expected results from calcCoefficients.py when run from the terminal. However fetch.php returns NULL when ran as an AJAX call.

calcCoefficients.py:

```
import sys
import json
import numpy
# Read the xValues and yValues from the command-line arguments
x_values = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
y_values = json.loads(sys.argv[2])
# Perform polynomial regression
coefficients = numpy.polyfit(x_values, y_values, 3)

# Print the coefficients as a JSON string
print(json.dumps(coefficients.tolist()))
```

I thought the issue was with the shell_exec() function being run from a web server, but adding shell_exec('mkdir test') to fetch.php works when run as an ajax call. I think the issue must be something to do with my webserver? I'm running XAMPP, but I do not know how to troubleshoot or even determine if this is the problem.

Here is the ajax call from charts.php

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./fetch.php",
    data: JSON.stringify(dataOut),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (coefficientsNumPy) {
        console.log(coefficientsNumPy);
    },
    failure: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: Since you use `dataType: "json"`, the script has to use `echo json_encode($coefficients);`, not `var_dump($coefficients);`

Comment: And since the Python script already returns JSON, you could just pass that through: `passthru($command);`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tried both methods, but I'm still getting the same results, NULL from ajax, and the expected coefficients from the terminal. According to the php docs, passthrough sounded like the cli friendly function for a webserver, but after it didn't work, I tried all the other commands. shell_exec(), exec(), system(), poopen(), etc. And they work the same way, calling from powershell, cmd, and WSL works, but not from browser

Comment: Use the Network tab to see the raw response from the PHP script, what does it contain? Also make sure you're sending the JSON you expect.